# how to solve deprecation of Twig_Function, Twig_Function_Method, Twig_Function_Node

Tags: symfony, twig

After update symfony from 2.3 to 2.7, I am getting many deprecation warning messages for which I found no link for solving that issue.

The warning message I am getting is:

```
DEPRECATED - The Twig_Function class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead.  -
Called from require() at line 154
Called from DebugClassLoader::loadClass()
Called from spl_autoload_call() at line 25
Called from require() at line 154
Called from DebugClassLoader::loadClass()
Called from spl_autoload_call() at line 22
Called from MenuExtension::getFunctions() at line 1282
Called from Twig_Environment::initExtension() at line 1263
Called from Twig_Environment::initExtensions() at line 1196
Called from Twig_Environment::getUnaryOperators() at line 371
Called from Twig_Lexer::getOperatorRegex() at line 65
Called from Twig_Lexer::__construct() at line 529
Called from Twig_Environment::getLexer() at line 557
Called from Twig_Environment::tokenize() at line 647
Called from Twig_Environment::compileSource() at line 382
Called from Twig_Environment::loadTemplate() at line 126
Called from TwigEngine::load() at line 50
Called from TwigEngine::render() at line 72
Called from TwigEngine::render() at line 97
Called from TwigEngine::renderResponse() at line 176
Called from Controller::render() at line 65
Called from DefaultController::indexAction()
Called from call_user_func_array() at line 3109
Called from HttpKernel::handleRaw() at line 3071
Called from HttpKernel::handle() at line 3222
Called from ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() at line 2444
Called from Kernel::handle() at line 34
```

For your information, this is the twig version I am using:

```
php  composer.phar show -i | grep twig
twig/extensions                      v1.0.1             Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                            v1.22.1            Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

**NB.** In my opinion, the deprecations come from the fact that some bundles I installed use some deprecated functions. So, below is composer.json file in case it could help.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",

    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",

    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",

    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",

    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v2.0.0-alpha3",
    "lunetics/locale-bundle": "v2.4.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "coresphere/console-bundle": "0.3.0",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "lunetics/timezone-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "1.4.0",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "1.2.*@dev",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable",
    "willdurand/geocoder": "@stable",
    "misd/guzzle-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
    "imagine/imagine": "0.5.*@dev",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "@stable",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "dev-master",
    "willdurand/geocoder-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@dev",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "0.10.0",
    "nomaya/social-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

**NB.** I have similar warning messages for `Twig_Function_Method`, `Twig_Function_Node`, ...

**NB.** This [link](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/deprecated.html) tells us that there are deprecations but without specifying how to solve them.

Comment: You could either change them or in composer.json not update to the latest twig version that has them depreciated.

Comment: **FIRST** Regarding composer, I already updated my bundles to the latested version and without changes. This means that it could some bundles *(even they are the latest version)* use some deprecated methods of twig. **SECOND** the deprecation warning is not telling me where to look for the error (which is file to fix??).

Comment: If your application contains any custom developed extensions for `Twig`, then this is the place you should look. If coding standards are followed, then this should normally be `src/BundleName/Twig/`. Take a look at twig's documentation about [creating functions and filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html).

Comment: I developed nothing with twig. That is why I said I guess that there is a bundle causing these deprecations. My problem is the log is not helping me to catch where is the deprecation...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the bundles causing me the deprecations. To find them, just look after the files containing the word `Twig_Function_Method` for example through this command:

```
grep --exclude-dir={'./app/cache/','./app/logs/'} -rnw '.' -e "Twig_Filter_Method"
```

The result was this:

```
./vendor/jms/translation-bundle/JMS/TranslationBundle/Twig/TranslationExtension.php:56:            'desc' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'desc'),
./vendor/jms/translation-bundle/JMS/TranslationBundle/Twig/TranslationExtension.php:57:            'meaning' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'meaning'),
./vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Twig/SerializerExtension.php:46:            'serialize'      => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'serialize'),
./vendor/nelmio/api-doc-bundle/Nelmio/ApiDocBundle/Twig/Extension/MarkdownExtension.php:22:            'extra_markdown' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'markdown', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
./vendor/knplabs/knp-time-bundle/Knp/Bundle/TimeBundle/Twig/Extension/TimeExtension.php:46:            'ago' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'diff', array(
./vendor/twig/twig/doc/deprecated.rst:45:  * ``Twig_Filter_Method``
./vendor/twig/twig/doc/advanced_legacy.rst:707:You can also use ``Twig_Filter_Method`` instead of ``Twig_Filter_Function``
./vendor/twig/twig/doc/advanced_legacy.rst:715:                'rot13' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'rot13Filter'),
./vendor/twig/twig/doc/advanced_legacy.rst:727:The first argument of the ``Twig_Filter_Method`` constructor is always
./vendor/twig/twig/doc/advanced_legacy.rst:747:                'date' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'dateFilter'),
./vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Filter/Method.php:12:@trigger_error('The Twig_Filter_Method class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFilter instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
./vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Filter/Method.php:23:class Twig_Filter_Method extends Twig_Filter
```

As conclusion, these are the bundles causing me deprecations: `jms/translation-bundle`, `nelmio/api-doc-bundle`, `knplabs/knp-time-bundle`.

I will be waiting that these bundles got update.

I hope the answer will be helping other.

Comment: You can temporary set some twig version in composer.json like I do:

"require": {
...
"twig/twig": "1.18.2",
...
},

Answer (score 6):

I found this thread because i got the same issues with updating twig.

In the logs you'll find this line:

```
/logs/symfony/dev.log:7000:[2017-04-05 10:10:57] php.INFO: The Twig_Function_Node class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead.
```

Maybe that help the next ones who will arrive here.

Just replace:

```
'form_range' => new \Twig_Function_Node(...);
```

with:

```
'form_range' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction(...),
```